# Can I get the original Token pattern in the parser program?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I wrote a demo code on the top of ANTLRv4, and that is shown as following:

```
String expression = "var c = a + b()";
        ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(CharStreams.fromString(expression));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(tokens);

        lexer.removeErrorListeners();
        parser.removeErrorListeners();
        CountingErrorListener errorListener = new CountingErrorListener();
        parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);
        
        Vocabulary vocabulary = lexer.getVocabulary();
        System.out.println("vocabulary : "+vocabulary.getDisplayName(4));
```

For the last line, the symbolic name `ID` will be shown on the console. The `ID` is defined in the .g4 file like

```
ID: [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
```

My question is that can I get the original ID pattern `[a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*` in my program by some class or method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that. What you could do is parse your grammar using ANTLR's own parser: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr/antlr4

You then create a listener that collects all lexer rule patterns in a `Map`.

A quick demo:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.Interval;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String source = "grammar T;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "parse\n" +
                " : ID+ EOF\n" +
                " ;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "VAR\n" +
                " : '$' ID\n" +
                " ;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "ID\n" +
                " : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*\n" +
                " ;";

        ANTLRv4Lexer lexer = new ANTLRv4Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
        ANTLRv4Parser parser = new ANTLRv4Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        LexerRuleListener lexerRuleListener = new LexerRuleListener(lexer.getInputStream());
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(lexerRuleListener, parser.grammarSpec());

        System.out.println("ID's pattern: " + lexerRuleListener.getPatternForToken("ID"));
    }
}

class LexerRuleListener extends ANTLRv4ParserBaseListener {

    private final Map<String, String> lexerRuleMap;
    private final CharStream inputStream;

    public LexerRuleListener(CharStream inputStream) {
        this.lexerRuleMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public String getPatternForToken(String tokenName) {
        return this.lexerRuleMap.get(tokenName);
    }

    // lexerRuleSpec
    //  : DOC_COMMENT* FRAGMENT? TOKEN_REF COLON lexerRuleBlock SEMI
    //  ;
    @Override
    public void enterLexerRuleSpec(ANTLRv4Parser.LexerRuleSpecContext ctx) {
        int startIndex = ctx.lexerRuleBlock().start.getStartIndex();
        int stopIndex = ctx.lexerRuleBlock().stop.getStopIndex();

        String text = inputStream.getText(new Interval(startIndex, stopIndex));

        lexerRuleMap.put(ctx.TOKEN_REF().getText(), text);
    }
}
```

Running the code above will print:

```
ID's pattern: [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```